# Plot resize and saving empty

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a heatmap overlap an image, using seaborn and matplotlib as shown in the code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 

df = pd.read_csv('/home/diegonachon/eye-tracker/eyedata/csv_heatmap/cl/Suj5_Control_HO_1ph.csv')
df['xpl'] = pd.to_numeric(df['xpl'], errors = 'coerce')
df['ypl'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ypl'], errors = 'coerce')
df = df[(df['event'] == 'FIX') & (~(df['xpl'].isnull()))]
hmax = sns.kdeplot(x = df.xpl, y = df.ypl, cmap="Reds", shade=True, bw_adjust= 0.6, clip = ((0,800), (0,600)), 
                   alpha = 0.6, antialiased = True)
hmax.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

map_img = mpimg.imread('/home/diegonachon/eye-tracker/eyedata/asd.jpg') 

plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 800, 0, 600])

# image = plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 800, 0, 600], aspect = 250)
# figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
# plt.imsave('test.png', image)
# plt.savefig('fig8_6_80dpi.png')   

plt.show()
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkDoK.jpg

1. The first thing is that I can't resize it, I've tried changing 'aspect' and 'figsize', but nothing happen (as the code shown on comment)
2. When I tried to save the plot generate, is either and empty file (savefig) or an error (uncommenting image = plt.imswho()....) - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape')

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I have made to your code. As I don't have access to your data, so I have used random numbers instead but this will give you the idea. Refer to the UPPERCASE comments for the answers.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 

# CREATED FOR TEST
x = np.random.rand(100,)
y = np.random.rand(100,)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)) # YOU CAN MODIFY FIGSIZE FROM HERE
ax = sns.kdeplot(x = x, y = y, cmap="Reds", shade=True, bw_adjust= 0.6, 
clip = ((0,800), (0,600)), 
               alpha = 0.6, antialiased = True)
ax.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

# map_img = mpimg.imread('/home/diegonachon/eye-tracker/eyedata/asd.jpg') 

#plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 800, 0, 600])

# image = plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 800, 0, 600], 
#aspect = 250)
# figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
# plt.imsave('test.png', image)
# plt.savefig('fig8_6_80dpi.png')  

# THIS WILL SAVE YOUR IMAGE AS A PNG FILE
plt.savefig('test.png') 
plt.show()
```